# Access db via web service

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, windows-phone-7

Is it efficient using a web service to access database objects?

I'm developing a win phone app and a web app. Both of them will use the same db. Should I create one web service for two apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shared webservice is definitely the right way to go. That's really the point of a service, to be able to access the same business and data logic from multiple places (assuming both places are doing the same thing of course). It also acts as a natural security buffer between your app and database - so your database only needs to accept connections from the service, as opposed to multiple client applications.

As far as the technology, since both of your clients are Microsoft, you can use WCF as your service as opposed to a traditional SOAP service. Or you can go with something more universally accepted, like WebAPI with JSON. Lots of options there.